# Wpf, does it have an alt text similar to html?

Tags: wpf, xaml, text, alt

I want to be able to mouse over text that is cut off in an element and then have the full text appear in a box similar to alt text in html (The text that appears when hovering the mouse over images).

Is there already a feature like this present? I haven't come across anything in my searches describing this.

Comment: Are you looking for [ToolTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/tooltip-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm talking about. I'm surprised I didn't come across this. Thank you :)

Comment: I recommend it as follows (eg in a TextBox or TextBlock): ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"